# React.lazy with react-router 3

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there some way to use React.lazy and React.Suspense with the old react-router (3)?
If yes, how to implement React.lazy and React.Suspense with react-router 3?

Answer (score 0):

Tried myself and failed - I dont think its possible.
Alternative solutions:

- Use lazy loading libraries like [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable)
- Upgrade react-router to latest (or at least v4)